# Navigating to view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In a storyboard I have added 2 views. On each there's a TabBar (I'm doing navigation programmatically).

[image]

I added ViewController class to my view with table:
MediaListViewController.h
MediaListViewController.m

And on my main view i do this:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if(item.title!=@"All")
    {

         MediaListViewController *tableViewController =[[MediaListViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

It enters MediaListViewController loaded function, but my view from StoryBoard doesn't sghow up. just black screen.

What am i doing wrong?

I finally did this, almost...

**PROBLEM 2:**

I have added this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    MediaListViewController *viewController = (MediaListViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Table"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

But now, for some reason TabBar doesn't show up - **how to fix it?**
As you can see from screenshot - there is TabBar

Comment: Please include the code of how you are creating the views.

Comment: Do you actually load your controller from the storyboard? Alloc/init isn't enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints weren't set correctly, thats why my app TabBar was somewhere out of rang of display

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to set frame of your tableViewController? 
Try to put tableViewController.frame = CGRectMake (some rect);

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: use this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1